# Delete an element from an array that has been randomly selected

Tags: python, arrays

```
import random
x = ['England', 'Russia', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Algeria', 'Cameroon', 'Ivory Coast', 'Ghana', 'Nigeria', 'Australia', 'Iran', 'Japan', 'Korea Republic', 'Belgium', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Croatia', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Switzerland', 'Costa Rica', 'Honduras', 'Mexico', 'USA', 'Argentina', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Ecuador', 'Uruguay', 'Portugal']
x.pop(random.randint(0,len(x)-1))
print (random.choice(x))
```

I now want to delete the `random.choice` from the array.

Comment: What language you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Your line with `x.pop` already removes a random item.  If you mean remove a random item by value, you can use `x.remove`:

```
to_remove = random.choice(x)
print(to_remove)
x.remove(to_remove)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you go:

```
to_remove = random.choice(x)
print to_remove
x.remove(to_remove)
```

But your code is pretty strange. You are indeed removing an item from your code by `x.pop(random.randint(0,len(x)-1))`. The difference from `x.remove()` is that list.pop() removes by index and returns variable and `list.remove()` removes by value.
Thus by performing both `pop` and `remove` you are removing two random items from your `x`.